# How to read the file from HTML fileu ploader

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and javascript but I am trying to upload a csv file and retrieve its data but I am having trouble in accessing the file specified in the file uploader. Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="modal-body">

    <input type="file" id="group-agent-file"/>
    <button type="button" id="btn-group-agent-upload" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" title="Edit">Upload</button>

</div>
```

and here is my function

```
function test(file) {
alert('ok');

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: file,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {

        var data1 = $.csv.toObjects(data);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(data1[0]));

    }
});
}
```

and the event that will execute the function

```
$("#btn-group-agent-upload").on("click", function () {

    var file = $("#group-agent-file").val();

    test(file);

});
```

but I get this error message

> Failed to load file:///C:/fakepath/test.csv: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

how can I do this?

Comment: You need to run a local web server to use AJAX. You can't do it by simply opening an HTML file in your browser.

Comment: so how can i do this?

Comment: If you're on Windows, the easiest way is to use a packaged solution like XAMPP

Comment: is it that impossible to use native HTML file API and jquery ajax?

Comment: Hope this helps. https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-Parse-and-display-CSV-Text-file-using-JavaScript-jQuery-and-HTML5.aspx

Comment: For local web server `200 ok` extension on chrome is best....!